# "Corrupted NFSS Tables" Using `otftotfm` and Fontenc

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I have just converted some OTF fonts using `otftotfm`; these fonts were created using a custom encoding I wrote called `EL` (I needed to modify the `T1` encoding to include extra ligatures). When I try to test whether the font works in a simple file as follows, I get the following output. What is causing the "Corrupted NFSS tables" message, and how can I resolve the issue?

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EL/cmr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EL/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 100.

! Corrupted NFSS tables.
wrong@fontshape ...message {Corrupted NFSS tables}
                                                  error@fontshape else let f...
l.100 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont
```

I created the fonts using the following command.

```
otftotfm -a -e el.enc -fcalt -fdlig -ffrac -fkern -fonum -fordn -fpnum -fsinf \
-fsmcp -fsubs -fsups -fzero --vendor crimson Crimson-Roman.otf \
Crimson-Roman
```

Here is the test file I am using to check whether the font works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[EL]{fontenc}
\pdfmapfile{crimson.map}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{Crimson}
\begin{document}
The
\end{document}
```

The files `elenc.def` and `elcrimson.fd` are both visible to pdfTeX, as I have verified using `kpsewhich`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might try with `\DeclareFontSubstitution{EL}{Crimson}{m}{n}` adding also `\DeclareErrorFont{EL}{Crimson}{m}{n}{10}`

Comment: @egreg Where would I put the declaration? If I try to place it above `\usepackage[EL]{fontenc}`, I get the error "Encoding scheme 'EL' unknown". If I place it after `\usepackage[EL]{fontenc}`, it does not help, since the error seems to originate from the code in `fontenc`, which has already been parsed.

Comment: You don't have `fontspec`; are you meaning `fontenc`? I'd say `\usepackage[T1,EL]{fontenc}` and then define a small package `crimson.sty` with the needed font declarations.

Comment: Oops, yes, I meant to say `fontenc`, not `fontspec`.

Comment: I tried doing this, but I still get the same compilation error (pdfTeX is still trying to load `EL/cmr/m/n`, which does not exist). I can provide a file called `elcmr.fd` which resolves the issue, but I am guessing that this is the wrong way to solve the problem.

Comment: @void-pointer: Put the two commands mentioned by egreg in `elenc.def` (behind the line `\DeclareFontEncoding{EL}{}{}` which declares the encoding.

Comment: @egreg @UlrikeFischer Thanks! Putting the two commands after the `\DeclareFontEncoding{EL}{}{}` line in `elenc.def` fixed the issue. Would one of you like to post this as the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add

```
\DeclareFontSubstitution{EL}{Crimson}{m}{n}
\DeclareErrorFont{EL}{Crimson}{m}{n}{10}
```

to your `elenc.def` file, just after

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{EL}{}{}
```